# onblur() event stops onclick() event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textbox which has an onblur() event and a button with onclick().
But when I type something in the textbox and, without clicking my cursor away from the textbox, click on button only the onblur() event fires. It will stop the onclick event of  button.

```js
function onblur() {
  alert("onblur");
}

function fnValidate() {
  alert("Validate");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtUserName" onblur="fnUserChange()" class="User_Name" placeholder="User Name">

<button name="button" type="button" class="action_button primary" id="btnsave" onclick="return fnValidate();">Capture User</button>
```

Comment: Share your code please.

Comment: <input type="text" id="txtUserName" onblur="fnUserChange()" class="User_Name" placeholder="User Name">

<button name="button" type="button" class="action_button primary" id="btnsave" onclick="return fnValidate();">Capture User</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function onblur()
{

alert("onblur");
}

function fnValidate()
{
alert("Validate");
}
</script>

Comment: Use `console.log` instead of alert.  Alert changes focus.

Comment: i have used the blockUI() in my function .

Comment: $.blockUI();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET", url: Url,
                    async: true, cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data == "Exsist") {
                            alert("User Already Exsist");
                            txtUN.value = "";
                            return false;
                        }

Comment: @Mohit edit your question with formatted code, instead of posting this kind of things in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function fnUserChange() {
  console.log("onblur");
}

function fnValidate() {
  console.log("Validate");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtUserName" onblur="fnUserChange()" class="User_Name" placeholder="User Name">
<button name="button" type="button" class="action_button primary" id="btnsave" onclick="fnValidate();">Capture User</button>
```

Comment: Check this code. You might want to something like this

Answer (score 1):

As @JeremyJStarcher said in the comments, the fact that you use `alert` changes the focus and therefore produces a false negative. Your code works if you use `console.log` (and the correct function name. `fnUserChange()` was not defined.)

```js
function fnUserChange() {
  console.log("onblur");
}

function fnValidate() {
  console.log("Validate");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtUserName" onblur="fnUserChange()" class="User_Name" placeholder="User Name">

<button name="button" type="button" class="action_button primary" id="btnsave" onclick="return fnValidate();">Capture User</button>
```